# Jquery - Is it possible to remove element with break line after if there two or more classes with same name in one td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to remove element with duplicate class name in td ? Example: There are multiple td in table in td there should be only one class `.price1` and `.price2` if there are duplicates it should remove them and leave only original one in td. Thank you very much for help or advice.

Example:

```
<td>.price1 .price2</td> <- original one , 
<td>.price1 .price2<br />.price1 .price2</td> <- duplicate
```

Comment: how could we know the original one? the first appeared?

Comment: @King King Example: `<td>.price1 .price2</td> <- original one` , `<td>.price1 .price2<br />.price1 .price2</td> <- duplicate`

Comment: @user3656119 What the..? Are .price1 and .price2 texts of td..?

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy <span class="price1">100</price> , <span class="price2">200</price> for example.

Comment: @user3656119: Make up your mind, are they `td` elements or `span` elements?

Comment: are you sure, you can not do something at construction time?

Comment: spans inside td element

Comment: Is the </br> required for counting as a duplicate? Are the duplicate spans always appear exactly twice?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6SqAJ/ is this what you are looking for..?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$("#relevanttable tr td:has('.price1,.price2'):not(:first)").remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6SqAJ/)